# Acumatica Bql with generics C#

Tags: c#, .net, acumatica

This is AcumaticaERP specific.  I have created a BaseBlcHelper class that looks like this:

```
public abstract class BaseBlcHelper<TBlcObject, TDacObject> :
                                                            PXGraph<TBlcObject>,
                                                            IBaseBlcHelper<TDacObject, TDacObject> where TBlcObject : PXGraph
                                                            where TDacObject : class, IBqlTable, new()
```

I've created this class because I'm thinking I can put some shared functionality in there.
Here is the issue.  When I have a select statement like this:

```
Vendor next_vendor = (Vendor)PXSelect<Vendor, Where<Vendor.vendor1099, Equal<True>>, OrderBy<Desc<Vendor.acctCD>>>.Select(this);
```

how would you resolve the the TDacObject (generic) object to "Vendor.vendor1099" portion of the query and so on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you would be creating Helper methods that takes the DAC Field parameter as a generic type.

Here's an example prototype that takes the generic Graph, DAC Type, Field Type and Field value as parameter:

```
public static List<TDacObject> Select<TFieldObject>(this PXGraph graph, object fieldParamValue)
    where TFieldObject : class,IBqlField
    where TDacObject : class,IBqlTable
{
       // 'graph' will be used to provide the required context for query execution
       // 'TDacObject' is a generic DAC type used in the query
       // 'TFieldObject' is a generic DAC type used in the query
       // 'fieldParamValue' is a generic value you can use in your query
}
```

The trick to craft and execute the query with generic types is to use the generic types to create a BQLCommand object. After that you can create a PXView object that takes the BQLCommand as input parameter. Finally you execute a Select method of the PXView to execute the BQL query.

Here's some sample code for a generic Select by ID method. It should give you a basic idea of the process:

```
// Roughly equivalent to:
// PXSelect<TDacObject, Where<TDacObject.TDacField, Equals<Required<fieldParamValue>>>>

// TDacObject below is extracted from the type 'fieldType.DeclaringType'
// You can substitute that for your generic DAC Type entity

public static List<T> SelectById<T, TField>(this PXGraph graph, object id)
    where TField : class, IBqlField
    where T : class, IBqlTable
{
    return SelectById(graph, typeof(TField), id).Cast<T>().ToList();
}

public static List<object> SelectById(this PXGraph graph, Type fieldType, object id)
{
    var select = CreateSelectCommand(fieldType);
    var view = GetView(graph, fieldType, select);

    return view.SelectMulti(id);
}

public static BqlCommand CreateSelectCommand(Type fieldType)
{
    return CreateSelectCommand(fieldType.DeclaringType, fieldType);
}

public static BqlCommand CreateSelectCommand(Type entityType, Type fieldType)
{
    Type required = BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(Required<>), fieldType);
    Type equal = BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(Equal<>), required);
    Type where = BqlCommand.Compose(typeof(Where<,>), fieldType, equal);

    return BqlCommand.CreateInstance(typeof(Select<,>), entityType, where);
}

public static PXView GetView(this PXGraph graph, Type fieldType, BqlCommand select)
{
    PXView view;
    graph.Views.TryGetValue(fieldType.FullName, out view);

    if (view == null)
    {
        view = new PXView(graph, false, @select);
        graph.Views.Add(fieldType.FullName, view);
        graph.EnsureCachePersistence(fieldType.DeclaringType);
    }

    return view;
}
```